# How to resolve "Unable to find a shape calculator for type '<class 'xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier'>'"

Tags: scikit-learn, onnx, onnxruntime, xgbclassifier, skl2onnx

I have trained a XGB classifier and want to convert it into onnx model. I am using skl2onnx for this and getting below error:

```
Unable to find a shape calculator for type '<class 'xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier'>'
```

Tried it resolving it after finding a below solution on google

```
update_registered_converter(
xgb, 'XGBoostXGBClassifier',
calculate_linear_classifier_output_shapes, convert_xgboost,
options={'nocl': [True, False], 'zipmap': [True, False, 'columns']})
```

My XGB training params are

```
xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(
booster="gbtree",  # Tree, Linear, or DART
# versbosity=1,      # Verbosity of printing messages
eta=0.0635,        # Learning rate
gamma=0.5,         # Minimum loss reduction to make a split
min_child_weight=1,# Minimum sum of instance weight needed in a child
subsample=0.55,    # Subsample ratio of the training instances
reg_lambda=3.2,        # L2 regularization term on weights
alpha=1,           # L1 regularization term on weights
objective="binary:logistic", # Binary classification
eval_metric=["auc", "error", "aucpr"], # Evaluation metrics for validation data
n_estimators=100,  # Number of boosting rounds
max_depth=8,       # Maximum tree depth
learning_rate=0.1, # Step size at each iteration
random_state=42    # Random seed for reproducibility)
```

Comment: Resolved it. I should be using 
"update_registered_converter(
    xgb.XGBClassifier, 'XGBoostXGBClassifier',
    calculate_linear_classifier_output_shapes, convert_xgboost,
    options={'nocl': [True, False], 'zipmap': [True, False, 'columns']})"